# Form Validation using Javascript inside PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple problem but no matter what I try I can't see to get it to work. I have a form on a php page and I need to validate the qty value on my form so that it doesn't exceed $qty (value pulled from mySQL) and is not less than zero. Sounds easy--hmm wish it were..lol! I had it checking if the value was numeric and in my attempts to make this work I even broke that--not a good morning..lol!

Here's a snip of my JavaScript Fn:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function checkQty(elem){
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
                return true;
            }else{
                alert("Quantity for RMA must be greater than zero and cannot be more than the original order!");
                elem.focus();
                return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The function is called from the submit button, onClick:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkQty(document.getElementById('qty')";">
```

I've tried:

```
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(numericExpression) || elem.value < 0 || elem.value > <? int($qty) ?>){
```

No dice....HELP!?!

Comment: tag changed, although type='text/javascript..lol!

Comment: Mikey how is this Java related? Why did you roll back the tag change? Is there something we all are not seeing?

Comment: It's not related--Gordon was offended I originally tagged javascript instead of java..lol!

Comment: @Mikey1980 He was not offended m8, its just like big big thing to misplace java with javascript or vice-versa, it would be like talking about car and thinking about carpet.

Comment: @Mikey1980 I wasn't offended. Java is just not an abbreviation for JavaScript. Java is a programming language very different to JavaScript. You should not say Java when you mean JavaScript. It's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try and view the source of the page and check if the $qty value is be printed out.

Also I think you need to change the or (||) to an and (&&) based on the original if statement, otherwise it will skip the limit checks.

Also echo the variable to print it out.

i.e.

```
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(elem.value.match(numericExpression) && elem.value < 0 && elem.value > <? echo $qty ?>){
```

Comment: also, beware of shortened PHP open tag `<?` - it doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: shouldn't it be actually `<?php echo $qty; ?>`? I think it should.

Comment: I though it worked.. but now if the $qty and form qty are both 1 it throws the alert--I am so confused :s

Comment: @Neal - the && doesn't make sense to me, "If form value qty is not numeric OR is less than zero OR is greater-than db's qty then..."

Comment: @Mikey - based on the original if statement i.e. if you just added the limit checks into the if statement, it would need to be an and.
i.e. if it's a number and greater than zero and less than qty return true, else error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkQty(document.getElementById('qty'));">
```

Comment: I think you mean:
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkQty(document.getElementById('qty'));">

Comment: @Will Morgan Yes a mistake which I didn't see, fixed now tnx

Comment: BINGO--That worked, but any idea how to to compare it to a PHP variable $qty?

Comment: @Mikey1980 you're gonna have to ask seperate question for that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the PHP value available to the javascript e.g.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 function checkQty(elem, max_value){
    if(parseInt(elem.value)>0
       && (parseInt(elem.value)<=max_value)){
            return true;
    }else{
            alert("Quantity for RMA must be greater than zero and less than original order!");
            elem.focus();
            return false;
    }
 }
 </script>
 ...
 <?php
     $max_value=(integer)method_of_fetching_max_value();
     print "<input type='submit' name='submit' 
             onclick='checkQty(document.getElementById(\"qty\", $max_value))'>  
     ";
 ?>
```

C.

Comment: WOW! I love that approach--however my HTML on this page is clean and mainly PHP free--easier for our designer, but will use this for other scripts going forward for sure! KUDOS!!

Comment: I tried your method and no dice... if $qty and form qty are both 1 it throws the error.